# Handle PROTECT ERROR in Django DeleteView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I am using Django `DeleteView` to delete items in my database. I have use separate template to show the delete confirmation message, but when I press the yes button I get `ProtectedError` since customer table is linked with Accounts table. Hence I want to handle the `ProtectedError` and give user another message in the same template.

Here is the code I have used to perform the delete:

```
class Customer(DeleteView):
    #Delete Customers
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'project_templates/delete_customer.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('inactive_customers')
```

It would be really great if someone can suggest me a method to handle this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to catch the exception. When you look at the `DeletionMixin`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L256

You can override the `post` method and achieve something like:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except ProtectedError:
        # render the template with your message in the context
        # or you can use the messages framework to send the message
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Remember to import: `from django.db.models import ProtectedError`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and overriding the delete() method worked for me on Django 3.2. I used the messages framework to display the error message - that requires additional setup (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/):

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError
from django.contrib import messages
.
.
.
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    try:
        self.object.delete()
    except ProtectedError:
        messages.error(request, "custom error message")
    finally:
        return redirect(success_url)
```

Comment: Note you probably want to replace `finally` by `else`. `finally` always executes whereas `else` only executes when there is no exception. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: In this particular example that was the intention - always redirect to success_url, but with the “custom error message” displayed if the ProtectedError exception occurred.

Comment: Ah if the success URL shows the `DeleteView`, this is correct yeah.