# Catch protected error and show its message to the user instead of bare 500 code

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

I'm building a photo archive. Via AJAX I add some information to frames (comments, notes, places etc.).

But now I want to organize deletion the frame.

This seems to be a relevant question I managed to find: [Handle PROTECT ERROR in Django DeleteView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775483/handle-protect-error-in-django-deleteview)

What I need is to inform the user: you are trying to cut the grass from under feet of other objects.

The answer by Berislav Lopac at that link above seems reasonable.

Now at the production server I get this: 

## Server Error (500)


In the debug mode, I can see ProtectedError.

**Could you help me understand how to show a meaningful message to the user in production? Just catch ProtectedError message and show it instead of Server Error (500).**

**models**

```
class Frame(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            blank=False,
                            null=False,
                            default="---",
                            verbose_name=_('type'))


class FramePlace(CommonUrlMethodsMixin,
                models.Model
                ):

    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame,
                              blank=False,
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              verbose_name=_("frame"))

    place = models.ForeignKey(Place,
                              blank=False,
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                              verbose_name=_("place"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem. I am using this below code. Hope this will help.

Here, to catch the `ProtectedError` below code is working.

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError

def delete(self, request):
    obj = self.get_object()
    try:
        obj.delete()
        return JsonResponse( {"error":""} )

    except ProtectedError as e:
        return JsonResponse( {"error":"somae relation exists"} )

    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse( {"error":"something went wrong"} )
```

> Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. Override the `perform_destroy` or `destroy` methods of the desired ViewSet
2. Add middleware to handle exceptions from all ViewSets

### 1 - ViewSet level (Specific)

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        try:
            return super(MyViewSet, self).perform_destroy(instance)
        except ProtectedError as exception:
            data = {
                'code': 'server_error',
                'message': _('Internal server error.'),
                'error': {
                    'type': str(type(exception)),
                    'message': str(exception)
                }
            }
            return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### 2 - Application level (General)

**middleware.py**

```
class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware that makes sure clients see a meaningful error message wrapped in a Json response.
    """    
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        data = {
            'code': 'server_error',
            'message': _('Internal server error.'),
            'error': {
                'type': str(type(exception)),
                'message': str(exception)
            }
        }
        return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'myapp.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `destroy` method - see [DestoryModelMixin in the docs](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/acf6582de474ad7f0c5f97d59208691c09c049c0/rest_framework/mixins.py#L89)

(Using Django 3.1.3)

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import MyModel
from .serializers import MyModelSerializer


class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        try:
            self.perform_destroy(instance)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        # if protected, cannot be deleted, show error message
        except ProtectedError as exception:
            message = f"Cannot delete as it is being used..."
            response_msg = {
                "code": "server_error",
                "message": _("Internal server error."),
                "error": {"type": str(type(exception)), "message": message},
            }
            return Response(response_msg, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```